# Eclipse comes with windowbuilder, which wizard should I start with?

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

I just find out that windowbuilder comes with the original Eclipse package. There are project palette, application window, japplet, jdialog, jdialog, jframe, jinternalframe, jpanel, swing automatic databinding. Which one should I start with and how to learn more?

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse IDE, Window Builder is one more Editor for handling java source files.
So you should be able to open all java classes with it. Right click on any java class and select open with menu option. You should see "WindowBuilder Editor" as an option there.

Note that this editor may not show any content in Design or Bindings tab for any non-GUI classes (e.g. interfaces).